# Shell script to rename multiple files from their parent folders name

Tags: bash, script, shell-script, rename, bash-scripting

I have a file structure like  this:

- 00000010

  - 000000001.file1
  - 000000001.file2
- 00000020

  - 00000003.file1
  - 00000003.file2
  - 00000003.file3
- ...

So there are folders with 8-digit names containing one ore more files with name starting with 8-digit numbers. But theses filenames are – let's say – out of sync. So Now I try to rename them recursively in bash to archive:

- 00000010

  - 000000010.file1
  - 000000010.file2
- 00000020

  - 00000020.file1
  - 00000020.file2
  - 00000020.file3
- ...

My script does look like:

```
#! /bin/bash

find * -maxdepth 1 -name "*" -type d | while read -r dir
do
        rename 's/$dir\/[0-9]{8}/$dir/' *
done
```

But this is not working and gives errors like

> Global symbol "$dir" requires explicit
>   package name at (eval 1) line 1.

How could I write it to rename the files according to their folder names?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861208/shell-script-to-rename-multiple-files-from-their-parent-folders-name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from another answer I learned, that I have to use

```
rename "s/$dir\/[0-9]{8}/$dir\/$dir/" $dir/*
```

Just in case anyone has the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I do not really like the answer where `$dir` is interpolated into the pattern. It could lead to unexpected results if the directory would e.g. contain a character that gets interpreted as a special regexp token.

I would rather match the files directly in the pattern, negating the need to loop over the directories and just use a regular glob.

```
rename 's#([^/]+)/[^/]+(\.file[0-9]+)$#$1/$1$2#' base_directory/*/*
```

where the glob hits the individual files within the directories (it could even be specified to `base_directory/*/*.file*`, or similar, but it should not matter here).

Note that this is the full command, without need for the `find` construction.

- I use `#` as separator instead of the "regular" `/` to avoid having to escape that in the patterns.
- I capture the (greedy) group of "not a directory separator", followed by a directory separator, followed by a file name and line end. This makes the first capture group be the parent directory for each file.
- The first portion of the file name is discarded, except for the ending to keep the ordinal suffix.

I chose to use a more general approach than to assume that the files were all 8 characters long, but the real difference is that I neither need the `find` construct nor to cram the `$dir` variable into the (possibly unsafe) regexp environment.